# Polymorphic callback function not recognized

Tags: javascript, callback, fetch

I am getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: modNums is not a function`. I am following a guide and what I have below is roughly similar to what they did.

Is the issue coming from the fact that I am trying to call the callback inside of a fetch callback? How can I make the modNums function get called? Mind you modNums is just the name of the parameter and there are multiple function that are meant to be accepted for that function value (hence polymorphism).

```
function updatePageText (chapter, page, modNums) {
  fetch("../../assets/json_files/parsedPages.json")
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      modNums(chapter, page, data);
```

_

```
updatePageText(chapterNum, pageNum, increasePage);
```

Comment: How is `increasePage` defined? Are you sure you are passing a function?

Comment: function increasePage(pageNum, chapterNum, text) { ... }

Comment: What is logged when you add `console.log(modNums);` to the `updatePageText` function?

Comment: The console output is "undefined".

Comment: please give us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Void, then `increasePage` is not defined at the time of the function call. Please post the full code.

Comment: I figured it out. You must always add a function in the arguments if it expects a function. I had one line where I called updatePagesText with only 2 arguments.